# jQuery and CSS not working properly in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

When I have 2 instances of grid, the jquery does not pick up the second grid list, but it does for the first. Both grids also work in Opera, Chrome, Safari and Firefox..just not IE.

**html:**

```
<ul id = grid>
     <li><div class = "something><div class = hidden>hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something><div class = hidden>hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something><div class = hidden>hi</div></div></li>
</ul>

<ul id = grid>
     <li><div class = "something><div class = hidden>hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something><div class = hidden>hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something><div class = hidden>hi</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
.hidden
{
float: left;
display: none;
width: 150px;
height: 150px
}

.something
{
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 150px
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#grid li").hover(
            function (e) {
                var index = $('#grid li').index(this);
                $(".hidden").eq(index).show();
                },
            function(e) {
                var index = $('#grid li').index(this);
                $(".hidden").eq(index).hide();
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make your IDs unique, here is a good resource on how to create valid IDs: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). You JS needs a little work to only select the `.hidden` elements that are descendants of the grid you are currently hovering over and your class declarations for the `.something` divs need a closing quote:

html:

```
<ul class = "grid">
     <li><div class = "something"><div class = "hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something"><div class = "hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something"><div class = "hidden">hi</div></div></li>
</ul>

<ul class = "grid">
     <li><div class = "something"><div class = "hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something"><div class = "hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class = "something"><div class = "hidden">hi</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        //using the `.children()` function will be faster than $('.grid li')
        $(".grid").children('li').hover(
            function (e) {

                //since $(this) gets used more than once its a good idea to cache it
                var $this = $(this),

                    //to get an index you can just call `.index()` in an element and it will give you that element's index with respect to its siblings
                    index = $this.index();
                $this.find(".hidden").eq(index).show();
                },
            function(e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    index = $this.index();
                $this.find(".hidden").eq(index).hide();
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Docs for `.index()`: http://api.jquery.com/index

Answer (score 2):

ID's must be unique. Try using a class instead.

Answer (score 2):

you're missing quotes after the `something` class. this works in IE9 and FF8 http://jsfiddle.net/2QK8u/ and your IDs must be unique

Answer (score 2):

id's of html elements must be unique to the page, if you're wanting to apply something to multiple elements, use classes...

There are also a few missing quotes and spacing issues.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="grid">
     <li><div class="something"><div class="hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class="something"><div class="hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class="something"><div class="hidden">hi</div></div></li>
</ul>

<ul class="grid">
     <li><div class="something"><div class="hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class="something"><div class="hidden">hi</div></div></li>
     <li><div class="something"><div class="hidden">hi</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".grid li").hover(
        function (e) {
            var index = $('.grid li').index(this);
            $(".hidden").eq(index).show();
            },
        function(e) {
            var index = $('.grid li').index(this);
            $(".hidden").eq(index).hide();
        }
    );
});
```